# How to let users upload a file to server

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have a page, and I want it to allow users to upload a file to my server so that I can see it later. I have already gotten started, but when you click submit, it takes you to 500 error. Here is what code I have so far:

HTML:

```
<form action="uploadfile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
Choose File: 
<input name="userfile" type="file">
<p></p>
<p class="section-content"><input type="submit" value="Upload File"></p>
</form>
```

PHP: (named uploadfile.php)

```
<?php 
    $path = "files/"; $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $path)) { 
        echo "Success uploading". basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']); 
    } else{ 
        echo "Error when uploading file."; 
    } 
?>
```

In HTML, there is a button to choose the file and one to submit. The submit button takes you to uploadfile.php, and that appears as 500 - internal server error. Note that it does not just say 'Error when uploading file' like it should when there is an error.
I am new to PHP, so I don't know if I am doing something completely wrong, or maybe there is a way to do it in Javascript, which I am slightly more experienced in?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: I have tried 2 different browsers (Chrome and Edge)

Comment: You should start by looking at the web servers error log and see what the error message is.

Comment: I have edited your code, do you see the typos?

Comment: do you usually declare php variables like this "$ path"

Comment: Please add error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set("display_errors",1); to view the exact error.

Comment: I checked your code and it seems to be working fine. Just remove the space between $ and path. It should be $path.

Comment: enable error reoporting in php.ini file
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
this line may be commented on server in php.ini file
make suer path you try to save the file ,exist on server

Answer (score 0):

### corrected

> use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] instead of basename()

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/your root file name/files';
       $name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
       $tmp_name = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

       move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path.'/'.$name);
```